# SX promotion ad help request question

Tags: discussion

Over at academia.sx we are looking to create a community promotion ad to help us get out of beta. https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/community-promotion-ad-to-run-on-other-ses

We were thinking that it would be nice to create a "coat of arms" type academic seal. Would it be appropriate to ask "how to create an academic seal in LaTeX?" I would be willing to add a bounty in thanks for the effort.

Comment: why not?  some really amazing graphics have come out of this site, at least from the related blog.  (looking at the graphics on the linked site reminds me that i've wanted for a long time to needlepoint the harvard logo with an unobtrusive, two-letter alteration: "va ni tas" instead of "ve ri tas".)

Comment: My humble attempt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xxNrc.png `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I have no asked the question on the main site. Hopefully you will add your answer there.

Comment: @Daniel: Sadly, this drawing was not made with LaTeX. Altough I could export it to either PSTricks or TikZ, I don't think it would be fair. I'll wait a few more. `:)`

Comment: Here is a link to the question on the main site, in case anyone is interested: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79147/17427